# Attribute Error for related_name field in django rest framework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting the following Error

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `children` on serializer `ParentSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Child` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'Child' object has no attribute 'children'.

Here's my model.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

and my serializers.py

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('id','name')

class ChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id','name')

class ParentChildSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('id', 'name','children')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ... creation logic ...
        return parent

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ... update logic ...

        return instance
```

I am using `related_name` and `Many=True`, which are the other answers on SO for similar questions.

Comment: I figured out that I was setting the `queryset = Child.objects.all()` in the ViewSet, when I changed it to the `Parent.objects.all()` it worked like a charm

Comment: you should also your question and mark it as resolved.